# How to use both withWidth and withStyles as higher order component on a functional component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, higher-order-components

I am trying to use both `withStyles` and `withWidth` HOC in the same functional component in my project. I am stuck and not understanding how to use them both.

Here is my code:

```
....
import {widthStyles, withWidth} from "@material-ui/core";
....
function func({ classes, width }) {
  const isSmallScreen = /xs/.test(width);

  return (
......Some Code that uses both withStyles and withWidth.....
  );
}

export default (withWidth(), withStyles(style))(func);
```

I am not getting how to solve this!!

Please Help

Thank you!!

Comment: haha, normally HOC is stackable as a function call. `B(A(Component))`, assuming `A` and `B` both HOCs.

Comment: Lol, Thank You!!

Comment: Your line is  very creative, BTW @Satyam.

Comment: @windmaomao Sorry!! Which line are you mentioning?